# Нужна ли запятые в данной фразе?

Tags: пунктуация

Ах, если искра столь ярка, то, каково же пламя!

Answer (score 1):

*Ах, **если** искра столь ярка, **то** каково же пламя!*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным условия, составной союз ЕСЛИ...ТО, ставится только одна запятая.

Сравнить: *Каково ж пламя, если искра столь ярка!*  Здесь используется союз ЕСЛИ.